# how to whitelist IPs on google compute engine?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

One of the ISPs is unable to access my website hosted on google compute engine, how to whitelist their IP blocks?
I dont see any IP blocked in `iptables` of individual linux machines running behind the load balancer.

Update 1: The firewall rule which allows incoming traffic from any source(Allow from any source (`0.0.0.0/0`) - `tcp 80`) is already added to these gce machines.

Update 2: Further analysis has resulted in the following observations
(We took the client on a remote call):

1. `http://mywebsite.com` is not loading while `https://mywebsite.com` is loading. This is witnessed only by this user, other users are able to access the site on both http and https.
2. Contacted the ISP provider and confirmed that there are other machines from that ISP which are facing the same issue. This means its not a client specific issue(browser, firewall, virus issue).
3. `ping mywebsite.com` is successful on the client machine.
4. `tracert mywebsite.com` results in reaching google's ISP without any packet loss, this is followed by a few request timeouts before it hits the IP of mywebsite. Sometime it never reaches the IP of mywebsite.com, all results after entering google ISP results in request time outs.

Traceroute example from the client's system is as follows:

`1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.10.1
  3    34 ms     9 ms    13 ms  103.194.232.3.rev.jetspotnetworks.in [103.194.232.3]
  4   102 ms    10 ms    13 ms  103.194.232.1.rev.jetspotnetworks.in [103.194.232.1]
  5    11 ms     9 ms    13 ms  115.42.32.65.rev.jetspotnetworks.in [115.42.32.65]
  6    86 ms    87 ms    87 ms  72.14.218.21 -----------> Google ISP
  7    89 ms    85 ms    85 ms  209.85.142.228 -----------> Google ISP
  8   121 ms   122 ms   121 ms  66.249.94.39
  9   145 ms   149 ms   144 ms  216.239.63.213
 10   207 ms   208 ms   212 ms  216.239.62.201
 11   200 ms   197 ms   197 ms  66.249.94.131
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20   243 ms   191 ms   191 ms  IP of mywebsite.com  -----------> Sometimes this is never witnessed`

Comment: which ISP's are unable to reach your website, and which are? many that would help in finding the problem.

Comment: ISP with IP block  `103.0.0.0/8` main traffic is from India

Comment: and which are able to reach it?

Comment: Thanks Janus for the reply. We have an audience of 550k users mostly from India, many of them (we can safely assume >90%) are able to reach.

Comment: you said that "Some of the ISPs are unable to access my website". which ISP's are unable to access the site?

Comment: Two users reported the issue, later I found that both of them are from the same ISP with IP block `103.0.0.0/8` - JetSpot Networks - is unable to reach.  "Mahanagar Telephone Nigam" - this ISP is able to reach. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Did you have the chance to fix this issue? If so, is it possible to post the answer so other people can benefit from it

Comment: No, we were not able to find the specific issue, it looked like traffic to http was being blocked at various stages. We reported to one/two of the internet providers and they resolved at their end without providing more insights. In order to quickly make everything work we moved our site to https completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the firewall rule, and you can ping or traceroute the server, it shouldn't be a Cloud Platform configuration issue. This really looks more as an ISP connection issue. As for the asterisks on the traceroute output it means that the router at that hop doesn't respond to the type of packet you were using for the traceroute, Google internal network usually does not respond to ICMP packets.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description of the issue, this relay on the ISP. As the GCP FW is correct and this only affects some specific user with a specific ISP. Probably the ISP has set some configuration in those users to block non encrypted websites.

The solution has been to switch completely to the encrypted protocol `https` which is recommended over `http`, as http works in plain text.